# How can I use Collections.sort() if I implement Comparable interface in the subclass?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I came up with a small problem while doing my homework.

I have a Person class

```
public class Person {
    protected String code;
    protected String name;
}
```

And a subclass called Student

```
public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Student>{

    private double grade;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student that){
        return Double.compare(grade, that.grade);
    }
}
```

The teacher wanted us to create a Professor class to manage Student using ArrayList

```
public class Professor {
    private List<Person> arr;

    public Professor() {
       arr = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

After adding about ten students to the ArrayList and we're asked to sort that list. The problem is, as far as I know, I cannot use Collections.sort(arr) since I declared it List< Person >, not List< Student >.

Did I misunderstand anything? Is there any way to use Collections.sort() in this situation or I have to write a method to sort it manually?

And he asked us to implement the Comparable interface in the class Student, also asked us to create List< Person > instead of List< Student >

EDIT: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. APPRECIATE ALL OF THE ANSWERS AND COMMENTS. THE ABOVE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED BY DOWNCAST List< Person > to List < Student >

Comment: If you plan to sort students in a way particular to students, then the comparator definitely belongs in that class.

Comment: Your class `Person` is most likely an *abstract* class. Then you can declare `Person` to implement the `Comparable` but do the actual code to implement`Comparable`   in th the subclasses of `Person` only

Comment: @Timothy Truckle I agree with you. With these requirements, it seems the most logical way.

Comment: Just think about it this way: If your `List<Person>` had a `Teacher` in it, how would you sort that with respect to the `Student`s in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The teacher wanted us to create a Professor class to manage Student
>   using ArrayList

So replace

```
private List<Person> arr;
```

by :

```
private List<Student> students;
```

In this way, you could invoke `Collections.sort(students)`  as `student` refers to a `List` of `Comparable` elements (`Student` implementing the `Comparable` interface).

---

**Edit  after the comment** :

The requirement is not very logical : you have to sort something (`List<Person>`) that is not sortable (as only `Student` implements `Comparable`).

In theses conditions, you have three ways :

- the simplest and the cleanest way (if you may use it).
  Make `Person` an `abstract` class that implements`Comparable` but keep it abstract in.
  In this way you would not need to use any cast. You could directly invoke 
  `Collections.sort()` with a `List<Person>`
- force the downcast from `List<Person>` to `List<Student>` and invoke 
  then `Collections.sort()`.
- perform yourself the sort but you should still do some casts if you want to use the `compareTo()` method of the `Student` class as `Person` is not a `Comparable` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is he forced us to use List < Person >. It really annoys the whole class

Comment: You are welcome. The requirement is really not logical.  I updated with 3 propositions.

Comment: Very appreciate it @davidxxx . It works well with the downcast option.

Comment: You are very welcome :) FIY : If an answer suits to your requirement, you should accept the answer rather than editing your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowing as person because the collection sort required to implement `implements Comparable<Person>` as the API is.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        list.sort(null);
    }
```

One way is as mentioned below post I am providing you another approach for sorting list using `Comparator`

```
class SortbyGrade implements Comparator<Student>
{
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of
    // roll number
    public int compare(Student a, Student b)
    {
         return Double.compare(a.grade, b.grade);
    }
}
```

//collection sort

```
Collections.sort(arr, new SortbyGrade());
```